# getting python to print out the rows from my csv that are between 2 numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have code at the moment that prints out the rows of data from a csv based on user input, this code is displayed below:

```
#allows user input to select a column and then select a value from that 

    column data = pd.read_csv('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/Locations.csv')
   rowcol = 0 #the colum that is being searched is column 0 row1 =
    int(input("Enter Number: ")) #enter in your first point on the map Eg
    15 row2 = int(input("Enter Number: ")) #enter in your 2nd point on the
    graph eg 18 result = data.iloc[[row1, row2]]
```

But now I want my code to also print out the rows that are between these 2 values that are entered (e.g if the user puts in 12 and 15 it prints out the rows for 12, 13, 14 and 15)

this is what I have at the moment but I'm not sure how to go further:

```
num_list = []
for i in range(row1+1, row2):
    num_list.append(i)
    
print(f'Numbers between 2 points are:\n{btwpoints}')
```

Comment: Would you please add an example(input and desired output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `range`:

```
df.iloc[range(row1, row2)]
```

If you need to include `row2` as well:

```
df.iloc[range(row1, row2 + 1)]
```

You should manage obvious exceptions anyway (like `row2 < row1`, or *out of bounds* situations).

*Out of bounds* situations could be mananged like this:

```
df.iloc[range(max(0, row1), min(df.shape[0], row2+1))]
```

Having `row2 <= row1` will return an empty `DataFrame` which can be an acceptable output

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking out [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library:

```py
# inputs
input_file = "tmp/input.csv"
column = "Price"
left_bound = 100
right_bound = 202

rows = (
    # read csv file, use header as column names
    Table.from_csv(input_file, header=True)
    # cast column values to int
    .update(**{column: c.col(column).as_type(int)}).into_iter_rows(dict)
)
converter = (
    # this one lets the left bound in, it is to be skipped
    c.drop_while(c.item(column) != left_bound)
    .take_while(c.item(column) != right_bound)
    .gen_converter()
)
filtered_rows = iter(converter(rows))

try:
    # skipping the left bound
    next(filtered_rows)
except StopIteration:
    print("no rows")
else:
    for row in filtered_rows:
        print(row)
```